# iOS: Writing a script that runs through an app's UI programmatically

Tags: iphone, ios, frameworks, ios-frameworks, ios-ui-automation

I've been trying to use the FoneMonkey framework for automation, but it's been having issues with `UIGestureRecogizer` objects. There are buttons tied to those `UIGestureRecognizer` objects, and this block is making me unable to switch between views. Thus, I would like to write a short script that programmatically triggers those objects, causing the app to change views.

I'm not sure if it's possible to mix regular code with FoneMonkey commands, but let's assume that it's feasible. How would I go about writing an app/program/script that traverses different views for an iPhone app? Is it even feasible without using UI Automation or some other framework?

Answer (score 0):

if your gestures are standard gestures like pitch, soon, swipe (left, right, top, bottom), then Latest version of the MonkeyTalk has some support, take a look at the following url.

http://www.gorillalogic.com/monkeytalk-documentation/monkeytalk-language-reference/command-reference